Two Java methods are very similar, but one runs while the other doesn't
I'm taking a Java course.
The two methods belong to the same class, and very similar other than the return type and one additional variable in the method that doesn't work.
This does not work (the code is compiled but not executed on BlueJ / does not show results in the console on Eclipse):
public int countAllGenes(String dna) {
    int count = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    while (true) {
        String gene = findGene(dna, startIndex);
        if(gene.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        count = count + 1;
        startIndex = dna.indexOf(gene, startIndex) + gene.length();
    }
    return count;
}

But this works:
public void printAllGenes(String dna) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    while (true) {
        String gene = findGene(dna, startIndex);
        if (gene.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(gene);
        startIndex = dna.indexOf(gene, startIndex) + gene.length();
    }
}

Adding the entire code below:
public class Part1 {
    public int findStopCodon(String dna, int startIndex, String stopCodon) {
        // This method returns the index of the first occurrence of stopCodon
        // that appears past startIndex and is a multiple of 3 away from startIndex.
        // If there is no such stopCodon, this method returns the length of the dna strand.
        int currIndex = dna.indexOf(stopCodon, startIndex+3);
        while (currIndex != -1) {
            int diff = currIndex - startIndex;
            if (diff % 3 == 0) {
                return currIndex;
            } 
            else {
                currIndex = dna.indexOf(stopCodon, currIndex);   
            }  
        }
        return dna.length();
    }

    public String findGene (String dna, int startingPt) {
       // Parse the strand and find if the sets of letters occur
       int startIndex = dna.indexOf("ATG", startingPt);
       int taaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAA");
       int tagIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAG");
       int tgaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TGA");
       // Return the gene formed from the "ATG" and the closest stop codon
       int currMin = Math.min(taaIndex, tagIndex);
       int minIndex = Math.min(currMin, tgaIndex);
       // If there is no valid stop codon and therefore no gene, return the empty string
       if (minIndex == dna.length()) {
           return "";
       }
       return dna.substring(startIndex, minIndex + 3);
    }
    
    public void printAllGenes(String dna) {
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (true) {
            String gene = findGene(dna, startIndex);
            if (gene.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(gene);
            startIndex = dna.indexOf(gene, startIndex) + gene.length();
        }
    }
    
    public int countAllGenes(String dna) {
        int count = 0;
        int startIndex = 0;
        while (true) {
            String gene = findGene(dna, startIndex);
            System.out.println(startIndex);
            if (gene.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            count = count + 1;
            startIndex = dna.indexOf(gene, startIndex) + gene.length();
            System.out.println(startIndex);
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Part1 p1 = new Part1();
        p1.printAllGenes("ATGxxxTAAxxxATGxxxTAGxxxATGxxxTGA");
        p1.countAllGenes("ATGxxxTAAxxxATGxxxTAGxxxATGxxxTGA");
    }
}

When run, Eclipse console just shows the results of p1.printAllGenes("ATGxxxTAAxxxATGxxxTAGxxxATGxxxTGA"); like below:
ATGxxxTAA
ATGxxxTAG
ATGxxxTGA


Define "doesn't work"

The first method is compiled but when run, the blue loading bar won’t stop and the terminal won’t show.
The second method runs in a second and prints the gene in the terminal.

Try running it separate from BlueJ (a terrible IDE imo). Perhaps the first example is looping forever and BlueJ is waiting for the program to complete to retrieve the output (if any output is done in #findGene).

better provide [mre] in such questions

please provide the findGene method and an example dna String to make your code reproducible.

Tried to run the entire code on Eclipse instead of BlueJ. On Eclipse, it shows no results. Also added the entire code for debugging details.

I actually added System.out.println(count) right before the return statement in countAllGenes to make sure that something is printed out

quick test -> code is never terminating - it is stuck in findStopCodon

@user85421 Just did that, but no results still.. thanks for help though!

maybe  currIndex = dna.indexOf(stopCodon, currIndex+1);

@user85421 wow, thanks! Hmm why does it create problem for countAllGenes only though?

because countAllGenes() never got executed - code never returned from printAllGenes() (that is why a [mre] was needed, or better, a debugger/IDE that shows if the executing terminated)

@user85421 I just ran the entire code with your suggestion, and it WORKED!! Thanks so much!

The Question has been reopened. You may post and accept an Answer to your own Question to mark this complete, and to help others in the future.

There is problem with your method findGene.
when the dna argument passsed to the method findGene does not include ATG in the range between startingPt argument and the end of the string, then startIndex in the method findGene
int startIndex = dna.indexOf("ATG", startingPt); // startPt = 33

will evaluate to -1. Passing the argument startIndex to the method findStopCodon in the next line:
int taaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAA"); // startIndex = -1

causes endless loop, which means that your program never returns from the findStopCodon method, when it's called with startIndex = -1.
To fix this problem, you can check if the startIndex is -1 (no ATG was found) and return empty string in this case.
this would be something like this:
    public String findGene (String dna, int startingPt) {
    // Parse the strand and find if the sets of letters occur
    int startIndex = dna.indexOf("ATG", startingPt);
    if(startIndex == -1){
        return "";
    }
    int taaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAA");
    int tagIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TAG");
    int tgaIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, "TGA");
    // Return the gene formed from the "ATG" and the closest stop codon
    int currMin = Math.min(taaIndex, tagIndex);
    int minIndex = Math.min(currMin, tgaIndex);
    // If there is no valid stop codon and therefore no gene, return the empty string
    if (minIndex == dna.length()) {
        return "";
    }
    return dna.substring(startIndex, minIndex + 3);
}


The question's already closed, but I wanted to show gratitude by leaving a comment. Along with @user85421's comment, your comment solved another problem I was experiencing last night. Thank you so much for helping me getting through this!
